# Typeorm find row that has not been commited in transaction

Tags: postgresql, transactions, nestjs, typeorm

in my database i have a 'companies' table with taxId UQ column.
In my code i have a companiesRepository class that have tree methods:

findCompany: Performs an SELECT to find company by an UQ (taxId)
createCompany: Performs an INSERT
findOrCreate: Recives a taxId and try to find using findCompany, if isnt found, calls createCompany to insert this company.

Since on my endpoints, i recieve an tree structure data of companies and invoices informations, im using, TypeORM as my ORM and it queryRunner to manage transactions and rollback in case of problems during the flow.

The things is, when i recieve and register an invoice, i need to associate it to a companyRow by an taxId, if this company is not register i register than, otherwise i just SELECT this company from the bank (using this findOrCreate method)

The problem is, on the same request payload, i can recive many invoices. Supposing that i recived an invoice from a company that has not been registered, my findOrCreate companyRepository method, will not found and will register this company. After this, its possible an common to recive another invoice from the same company, since i didnt commit the transaction yet, because the whole endpoint flow is not completed, the findOrCreate will not found this company, and try to create again, after all throwing an execption by violating UQ constrant.

How can i solve this?

Thank you.

Techs used:

"@nestjs/common": "^9.0.0",
"@nestjs/core": "^9.0.0",
"@nestjs/typeorm": "^9.0.1",
"typeorm": "^0.3.10"
"pg": "^8.8.0",

My ideas was: stop using transacion for creating companies (its working by now) but doesnt seem kinda right.

Or even, just for companies, dont use the endpoint flow queryManager, uses an own queryManager and commit right after created, so it can be founded after it.

But i would like to know if its possible to keep everything inside this endpoint/global queryManager, and still be able to found an row even if isnt commited on the database yet.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your findOrCreate method is not using the same connection and thereby the same transaction.

You should be able to see the effects of a current transaction in the same transaction, even if not committed.

Comment: I guess its working by now, thank you. I was using the transactionManager connection only for methods that changes the database (insert, remove...) I didnt thought that using the same queryManager on find it would also looking inside database not commited transactions from this queryManager connection.